# Не находит файл настроек (.properties)

Tags: java, gradle

Пишу плагин для IntellIj.
Создал проект по стандарту, > (Gradle) > выбрал (Java IntelliJ Platform Plugin)
Работает !!! но, решил вынести некоторые данные в файл (.propertys)

И столкнулся с такой проблемой.
**Не могу получить путь до файла (.propertys)** 
При попытке получить путь

```
File f = new File("xxx.properties");
String absolutePath = f.getAbsolutePath();
```

в `absolutePath`  приходит `C:\Users\xxx\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.jetbrains.intellij.idea\ideaIC\2020.2\4fe93bb81525f2fa7a6f0fd7ba41c3b9cce9e8b6\ideaIC-2020.2\bin\xxx.properties`

хотя сам файл лежит `E:\Java\Project\GitFolder\Название проекта\src\main\resources\xxx.properties`

Если указать абсолютный путь то всё конечно работает, но как получить `E:\Java\Project\GitFolder\Название проекта\src\main\resources\xxx.properties` средствами Java

Answer (score 0):

Система ищет файл `properties` в `CLASSPATH` проекта. Соответственно, надо место где он лежит включить в `CLASSPATH`

P.S. Надеюсь, что такое `CLASSPATH` вам объяснять не надо :)

Comment: Не сработало ( Скорей всего проблема именно в проекте. Так как стандартной точки доступа, типа Main нет. И загрузку производит Gradle. Возможно нужно что то добавить в файл build.gradle.

Comment: Попробуйте в gradle включить каталог где лежат properties в раздел `sourceSets `

Comment: Спасибо Попробую.